# symfony: what is the latest stable version in Github repository?

Tags: symfony

I have a doubt at this moment.. I'm wondering how to know what is the latest stable version in Github repository of symfony? Any help?

Using `symfony new project_name` it says it is 2.7.3, but how to know it in Github to fork it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GitHub you can look for tags. Only stable realeases are marked by tags with only version in name. Sometimes Symfony have Beta-versions. These versions are marked with tags too but always have appendix: `BETA`.

So for now the actual stable version is 2.7.4. You can see it in screenshot:
[image]

Comment: @thanks, anaway it said the stable version now is 2.7.3: http://symfony.com/roadmap

Comment: It is not updated yet. Many things are updated manually or have to wait some time while will be deployed new version (as for website). If you want to have latest news I recommend you to subscribe to their blog. Here: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-7-4-released you can see that 2.7.4 has been released 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the symfony road map.

**http://symfony.com/roadmap**

Comment: thanks, but how to know it in Github? how to find 2.7.3?I would like to fork the latest stable release.